# When are the operator norm and the Hilbert-Schmidt norm equal?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $H$ be Hilbert space and let $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ denote the usual operator norm and the Hilbert-Schmidt norm respectively. I know that if $T \in \mathscr{B}(H)$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, then $\|T\| \leq \|T\|_2$. Is there a particular type of operator for which $\|T\| = \|T\|_2$?

Comment: In the finite-dimensional case this occurs if and only if $T$ has rank-$1$.  I suspect that the same holds in general, but I have no proof off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equality occurs if and only if $T$ is a rank one operator.  One proof is as follows.

If $T$ is bounded then $\|T\|$ is finite, so we can exclude the case that $\|T\|_2$ fails to be finite.  Suppose then that $\|T\|_2$ is finite.  Then $T$ is compact and there exist countable orthonormal sets $(u_j),(v_j)$ such that
$$
T(x) = \sum_{j} \sigma_j  \langle x,v_j \rangle u_j
$$
where $\sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq \sigma_3 \geq \cdots$ are non-negative. It follows that
$$
\|T\|^2 = \sigma_1^2, \quad \|T\|_2^2 = \sum_{j} \sigma_j^2.
$$
These two can only be equal if $\sigma_j = 0$ for all $j \geq 2$, which occurs if and only if $T$ has rank $1$.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see the existence of the orthonormal sets $(u_j), (v_j)$? I assume we are approximating $T$ by finite rank operators $T_n$ and thus $T_nx = \sum_{j=1}^n \langle T_n x, u_j \rangle u_j$ for some orthonormal $(u_j)$. By Riesz there exist $v_j$ st. $T_n x = \sum_{j=1}^n \langle x, v_j \rangle u_j$. Now we could apply Gram-Schmidt to orthogonalize the $v_j$'s at the expense of the orthogonality of the $u_j$'s in the representation of $T_n$ above. What am I missing?

Comment: @400070 This sum over $u_j,v_j$ is just the singular value decomposition of a compact operator. Its existence can be proven as a consequence of the spectral theorem for compact operators (applied to $T^*T$).